# Why Elasticsearch is terminated if I bind mount a volume?

Tags: docker-compose, elasticsearch

In my docker-compose I setup an elasticsearch container:

```
version: "3.3"
services:

  elasticsearch:
   build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./dockerfiles/DockerfileElasticSearch
   networks:
      private:
      public:
        ipv4_address: ${IP_BASE}.4
   env_file: env/elasticsearch.env
   volumes:
      - "./volumes/elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data:rw"
   environment:
     - "discovery.type=single-node"
     ## Avoid test failures due to small disks
     ## More info at https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento/issues/488
     - "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled=false"
     - "index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete"

networks:
  private:
  public:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: ${IP_BASE}.0/24
          gateway: ${IP_BASE}.1
```

But the elasticsearch container upon `docker-compose up -d` is terminated:

```
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2023-09-25T07:45:25,470Z", "level": "ERROR", "component": "o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "d87be4eb6a30", "message": "uncaught exception in thread [main]", 
"stacktrace": ["org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: ElasticsearchException[failed to bind service]; nested: AccessDeniedException[/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes];",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:174) ~[elasticsearch-7.7.0.jar:7.7.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:161) ~[elasticsearch-7.7.0.jar:7.7.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86) ~[elasticsearch-7.7.0.jar:7.7.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:127) ~[elasticsearch-cli-7.7.0.jar:7.7.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) ~[elasticsearch-cli-7.7.0.jar:7.7.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:126) ~[elasticsearch-7.7.0.jar:7.7.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:92) ~[elasticsearch-7.7.0.jar:7.7.0]",
"Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: failed to bind service",
"at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:638) ~[elasticsearch-7.7.0.jar:7.7.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:264) ~[elasticsearch-7.7.0.jar:7.7.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:227) ~[elasticsearch-7.7.0.jar:7.7.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:227) ~[elasticsearch-7.7.0.jar:7.7.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:393) ~[elasticsearch-7.7.0.jar:7.7.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:170) ~[elasticsearch-7.7.0.jar:7.7.0]",
"... 6 more",
"Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes",
"at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:90) ~[?:?]",
"at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111) ~[?:?]",
"at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116) ~[?:?]",
"at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:389) ~[?:?]",
"at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:694) ~[?:?]",
"at java.nio.file.Files.createAndCheckIsDirectory(Files.java:801) ~[?:?]",
"at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:787) ~[?:?]",
"at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.lambda$new$0(NodeEnvironment.java:274) ~[elasticsearch-7.7.0.jar:7.7.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment$NodeLock.<init>(NodeEnvironment.java:211) ~[elasticsearch-7.7.0.jar:7.7.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.<init>(NodeEnvironment.java:271) ~[elasticsearch-7.7.0.jar:7.7.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:284) ~[elasticsearch-7.7.0.jar:7.7.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:264) ~[elasticsearch-7.7.0.jar:7.7.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:227) ~[elasticsearch-7.7.0.jar:7.7.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:227) ~[elasticsearch-7.7.0.jar:7.7.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:393) ~[elasticsearch-7.7.0.jar:7.7.0]",
"at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:170) ~[elasticsearch-7.7.0.jar:7.7.0]",
"... 6 more"] }
uncaught exception in thread [main]
ElasticsearchException[failed to bind service]; nested: AccessDeniedException[/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes];
Likely root cause: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:90)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:389)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:694)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createAndCheckIsDirectory(Files.java:801)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:787)
    at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.lambda$new$0(NodeEnvironment.java:274)
    at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment$NodeLock.<init>(NodeEnvironment.java:211)
    at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.<init>(NodeEnvironment.java:271)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:284)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:264)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:227)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:227)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:393)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:170)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:161)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:127)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:126)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:92)
For complete error details, refer to the log at /usr/share/elasticsearch/logs/docker-cluster.log
```

Instead if I remove the volumes section runs fine:

```
version: "3.3"
services:

  elasticsearch:
   build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./dockerfiles/DockerfileElasticSearch
   networks:
      private:
      public:
        ipv4_address: ${IP_BASE}.4
   env_file: env/elasticsearch.env
   environment:
     - "discovery.type=single-node"
     ## Avoid test failures due to small disks
     ## More info at https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento/issues/488
     - "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled=false"
     - "index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete"

networks:
  private:
  public:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: ${IP_BASE}.0/24
          gateway: ${IP_BASE}.1
```

Any idea why? How I can retain the elasticsearch data?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why but a working version of mine is to use `volumes` like this:

```
version: "3.3"
services:

  elasticsearch:
   build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./dockerfiles/DockerfileElasticSearch
   networks:
      private:
      public:
        ipv4_address: ${IP_BASE}.4
   env_file: env/elasticsearch.env
   volumes:
      - "elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data:rw"
   environment:
     - "discovery.type=single-node"
     ## Avoid test failures due to small disks
     ## More info at https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento/issues/488
     - "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled=false"
     - "index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete"

volumes:
  elasticsearch:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: './volumes/elasticsearch'

networks:
  private:
  public:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: ${IP_BASE}.0/24
          gateway: ${IP_BASE}.1
```

But you must make the folder `./volumes/elasticsearch` first.